# Jenkins Jmeter plugin - NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I have a Jenkins job set up to run a Jmeter test that was built using the JMeter GUI, but the build always fails, reporting a NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException.

This is what's shown in the JMeter.log file:

```
2013/07/22 10:28:16 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 91
------------------------------- : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 91
-------------------------------
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 91
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy : HTTPSamplerProxy
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:81)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 91
------------------------------- 
2013/07/22 10:28:16 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:91)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:724)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:702)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:353)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:207)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After far too much hunting about, I found [this thread](https://github.com/ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/20) in github.

Essentially, to make the project build successfully, all I had to do was search-and-replace the `HTTPSamplerProxy` with `HTTPSampler` in the .jmx test file, and the jenkins project now builds without a hitch. Joy!

Comment: This worked for me. My problem was a test bank created with Jmeter 2.8 and was trying to open it with 2.3, did the replacement and now is working. Another workaround could be updating jmeter to a newer version. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. the problem was the version of the Jmeter on the remote server was 2.6 and the one with which the .jmx file was created was 2.8. So i installed a lower version and recreated the .jmx file moved to the remote server and all was fine

Comment: This is what worked for me.  Updated the version on my Jenkins Slave to 3.2 and BAM! ran fine.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue please refer the below screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hcgd.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting `<ResultCollector>` from the JMX fixed the problem. JMX created in jmeter 3.1, running JMX under jmeter 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running jmeter 4.0 under jmeter-maven-plugin 2.9.0. Running mvn clean before running the test fixed the problem.